# wx Import Error

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to run this code. Previously, it was giving `No module wx` as an error. Then I downloaded the `wx` module and now it is giving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python24\player.py", line 2, in -toplevel-
import wx
File "C:\Python24\wx__init__.py", line 45, in -toplevel-
from wxPython import wx
File "C:\Python24\wxPython__init__.py", line 20, in -toplevel-
import wxc
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Here is my code:

```
import os
import wx
import wx.media
import wx.lib.buttons as buttons

dirName = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
bitmapDir = os.path.join(dirName, 'bitmaps')

########################################################################
class MediaPanel(wx.Panel):
""""""

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, parent):
    """Constructor"""
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    self.frame = parent
    self.currentVolume = 50
    self.createMenu()
    self.layoutControls()

    sp = wx.StandardPaths.Get()
    self.currentFolder = sp.GetDocumentsDir()

    self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer)
    self.timer.Start(100)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def layoutControls(self):
    """
    Create and layout the widgets
    """

    try:
        self.mediaPlayer = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
    except NotImplementedError:
        self.Destroy()
        raise

    # create playback slider
    self.playbackSlider = wx.Slider(self, size=wx.DefaultSize)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.onSeek, self.playbackSlider)

    self.volumeCtrl = wx.Slider(self, style=wx.SL_VERTICAL|wx.SL_INVERSE)
    self.volumeCtrl.SetRange(0, 100)
    self.volumeCtrl.SetValue(self.currentVolume)
    self.volumeCtrl.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.onSetVolume)

    # Create sizers
    mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    hSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    audioSizer = self.buildAudioBar()

    # layout widgets
    mainSizer.Add(self.playbackSlider, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    hSizer.Add(audioSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
    hSizer.Add(self.volumeCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    mainSizer.Add(hSizer)

    self.SetSizer(mainSizer)
    self.Layout()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def buildAudioBar(self):
    """
    Builds the audio bar controls
    """
    audioBarSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

    self.buildBtn({'bitmap':'player_prev.png', 'handler':self.onPrev,
                   'name':'prev'},
                  audioBarSizer)

    # create play/pause toggle button
    img = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(bitmapDir, "player_play.png"))
    self.playPauseBtn = buttons.GenBitmapToggleButton(self, bitmap=img, name="play")
    self.playPauseBtn.Enable(False)

    img = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(bitmapDir, "player_pause.png"))
    self.playPauseBtn.SetBitmapSelected(img)
    self.playPauseBtn.SetInitialSize()

    self.playPauseBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPlay)
    audioBarSizer.Add(self.playPauseBtn, 0, wx.LEFT, 3)

    btnData = [{'bitmap':'player_stop.png',
                'handler':self.onStop, 'name':'stop'},
                {'bitmap':'player_next.png',
                 'handler':self.onNext, 'name':'next'}]
    for btn in btnData:
        self.buildBtn(btn, audioBarSizer)

    return audioBarSizer

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def buildBtn(self, btnDict, sizer):
    """"""
    bmp = btnDict['bitmap']
    handler = btnDict['handler']

    img = wx.Bitmap(os.path.join(bitmapDir, bmp))
    btn = buttons.GenBitmapButton(self, bitmap=img, name=btnDict['name'])
    btn.SetInitialSize()
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, handler)
    sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.LEFT, 3)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def createMenu(self):
    """
    Creates a menu
    """
    menubar = wx.MenuBar()

    fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    open_file_menu_item = fileMenu.Append(wx.NewId(), "&Open", "Open a File")
    menubar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
    self.frame.SetMenuBar(menubar)
    self.frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onBrowse, open_file_menu_item)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def loadMusic(self, musicFile):
    """
    Load the music into the MediaCtrl or display an error dialog
    if the user tries to load an unsupported file type
    """
    if not self.mediaPlayer.Load(musicFile):
        wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % path,
                      "ERROR",
                      wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)
    else:
        self.mediaPlayer.SetInitialSize()
        self.GetSizer().Layout()
        self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, self.mediaPlayer.Length())
        self.playPauseBtn.Enable(True)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onBrowse(self, event):
    """
    Opens file dialog to browse for music
    """
    wildcard = "MP3 (*.mp3)|*.mp3|"     \
               "WAV (*.wav)|*.wav"
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, message="Choose a file",
        defaultDir=self.currentFolder,
        defaultFile="",
        wildcard=wildcard,
        style=wx.OPEN | wx.CHANGE_DIR
        )
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dlg.GetPath()
        self.currentFolder = os.path.dirname(path)
        self.loadMusic(path)
    dlg.Destroy()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onNext(self, event):
    """
    Not implemented!
    """
    pass

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onPause(self):
    """
    Pauses the music
    """
    self.mediaPlayer.Pause()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onPlay(self, event):
    """
    Plays the music
    """
    if not event.GetIsDown():
        self.onPause()
        return

    if not self.mediaPlayer.Play():
        wx.MessageBox("Unable to Play media : Unsupported format?",
                      "ERROR",
                      wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)
    else:
        self.mediaPlayer.SetInitialSize()
        self.GetSizer().Layout()
        self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, self.mediaPlayer.Length())

    event.Skip()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onPrev(self, event):
    """
    Not implemented!
    """
    pass

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onSeek(self, event):
    """
    Seeks the media file according to the amount the slider has
    been adjusted.
    """
    offset = self.playbackSlider.GetValue()
    self.mediaPlayer.Seek(offset)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onSetVolume(self, event):
    """
    Sets the volume of the music player
    """
    self.currentVolume = self.volumeCtrl.GetValue()
    print "setting volume to: %s" % int(self.currentVolume)
    self.mediaPlayer.SetVolume(self.currentVolume)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onStop(self, event):
    """
    Stops the music and resets the play button
    """
    self.mediaPlayer.Stop()
    self.playPauseBtn.SetToggle(False)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onTimer(self, event):
    """
    Keeps the player slider updated
    """
    offset = self.mediaPlayer.Tell()
    self.playbackSlider.SetValue(offset)

########################################################################
class MediaFrame(wx.Frame):

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Python Music Player")
    panel = MediaPanel(self)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MediaFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

It may be that I didn't install `wx` correctly. I am using Python 2.4 and I was unable to find the `wx` module for Python 2.4. I downloaded `wx` for Python 2.5 and pasted the wx folder into the Python 2.4 directory. Can you please guide me how to add the `wx` module in Python 2.4?

Comment: you dont see anything wrong with this?! "I downloaded wx for Python 2.5 and pasted the wx folder into the Python 2.4 directory." ... if not, i would say to downgrade to python 1.5 or upgrade to 3.3 ... just as useful ... it wont work ...

Comment: You shouldn't copy / paste libraries between python installations that have compiled extensions in them.  You could run into a binary incompatibility that will cause your extension to crash for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Check [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/).

The 2.8.10 version still has binary installers for 2.4