# Can't understand the error

Tags: python, wxpython, python-2.6

Given below is the error which I am getting while running the code (which is in my previous post [wx Import Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976683/wx-import-error/9976995#9976995)) in Python 2.6. Can anyone tell about this error? I am unable to understand it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python26\music_player_v1\player_skeleton.py", line 153, in <module>
frame = MediaFrame()
File "C:\Python26\music_player_v1\player_skeleton.py", line 148, in __init__
panel = MediaPanel(self)
File "C:\Python26\music_player_v1\player_skeleton.py", line 25, in __init__
self.layoutControls()
File "C:\Python26\music_player_v1\player_skeleton.py", line 46, in layoutControls
audioTBSizer = self.buildAudioToolBar()
File "C:\Python26\music_player_v1\player_skeleton.py", line 65, in buildAudioToolBar
self.rewind = SBitmapButton(self, -1, upbmp, (48, 48))
File "C:\Python26\Lib\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib\agw\shapedbutton.py", line 995, in __init__
self.SetBitmapLabel(bitmap)
File "C:\Python26\Lib\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\lib\agw\shapedbutton.py", line 1068, in SetBitmapLabel
image = wx.ImageFromBitmap(bitmap)
File "C:\Python26\Lib\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_core.py", line 3473, in ImageFromBitmap
val = _core_.new_ImageFromBitmap(*args, **kwargs)
PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "bmp.Ok()" failed at ..\..\src\msw\dib.cpp(148) in wxDIB::Create(): wxDIB::Create(): invalid bitmap
```

Comment: Include your code here, and the input and manner of invoking your programme that leads to this error, as well as any other details of the circumstances that cause this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wx Import Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976683/wx-import-error)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is entirely related to your problem, but the SWIG-generated wrappers won't hold onto any Python objects passed to any `set*()` methods or the like in wx. You will need to hold onto such objects yourself or you will experience strange errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an invalid bitmap.  In reading the tracebacks, it's usually the bottom traceback that's the most useful, and this one is saying that you have an "invalid bitmap".

Answer (score 0):

Your application cant find an image file, put all images in one file and in your code give the exact path where to find the images.That wil solve that error.